# Count of node of Hierarchical Data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hierarchical, mlm

i got a solution from link below. this works very fine, but I want to count of items at different levels instead of names. anybody can help how it is possible.
http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

```
CREATE TABLE category(
        category_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        parent INT DEFAULT NULL
   );

INSERT INTO category VALUES(1,'ELECTRONICS',NULL),(2,'TELEVISIONS',1),(3,'TUBE',2),
        (4,'LCD',2),(5,'PLASMA',2),(6,'PORTABLE ELECTRONICS',1),(7,'MP3 PLAYERS',6),(8,'FLASH',7),
        (9,'CD PLAYERS',6),(10,'2 WAY RADIOS',6);

SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY category_id;
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| category_id | name                 | parent |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   NULL |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |      1 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |      2 |
|           4 | LCD                  |      2 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |      2 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |      1 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |      6 |
|           8 | FLASH                |      7 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |      6 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |      6 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

following query on above table give result:-

```
SELECT t1.name AS lev1, t2.name as lev2, t3.name as lev3, t4.name as lev4
FROM category AS t1
LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS';

Result:-

+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
| lev1        | lev2                 | lev3         | lev4  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | TUBE         | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | LCD          | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | TELEVISIONS          | PLASMA       | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | MP3 PLAYERS  | FLASH |
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | CD PLAYERS   | NULL  |
| ELECTRONICS | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS | 2 WAY RADIOS | NULL  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

here i need to modify query to count of items at diffirent levels, instead of their names.
for example result from above data

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
| lev1        | lev2                 | lev3         | lev4  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------------+-------+
| ELECTRONICS | 2                    | 6            | 1     |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to `GROUP BY` and `COUNT DISTINCT` names

> ```
> SELECT t1.name AS lev1, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.name) as lev2, COUNT(DISTINCT t3.name) as lev3, COUNT(DISTINCT t4.name) as lev4
> FROM category AS t1
> LEFT JOIN category AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.category_id
> LEFT JOIN category AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.category_id
> LEFT JOIN category AS t4 ON t4.parent = t3.category_id
> WHERE t1.name = 'ELECTRONICS'
> GROUP BY t1.name
> ```
>
> ```
> lev1        | lev2 | lev3 | lev4
> :---------- | ---: | ---: | ---:
> ELECTRONICS |    2 |    6 |    1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=05246cbe00855062e7d157089fb2baa5)*

Comment: thanks.  I was missing COUNT with DISTINCT